# Adding Up Numbers From A List In Python

Tags: python, loops

basically i'm trying to complete a read file. i have made the "make" file that will generate 10 random numbers and write it to a text file. here's what i have so far for the "read" file...

```
def main():
    infile = open('mynumbers.txt', 'r')
    nums = []
    line = infile.readline()

    print ('The random numbers were:')
    while line:
        nums.append(int(line))
        print (line)
        line = infile.readline()

    total = sum(line)  
    print ('The total of the random numbers is:', total)

main()
```

i know it's incomplete, i'm still a beginner at this and this is my first introduction to computer programming or python. basically i have to use a loop to gather up the sum of all the numbers that were listed in the mynumbers.txt. any help would be GREATLY appreciated. this has been driving me up a wall.

Comment: He/she's a beginner guys, please cut them some slack!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate manually in Python (this isn't C, after all):

```
nums = []
with open("mynumbers.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        nums.append(int(line))
```

Now you just have to take the sum, but of `nums`, of course, not of `line`:

```
total = sum(nums)
```

Comment: typo: `infile` vs `file`. Instead of appending to a list you could just add the newly read integer to a total variable that was initialized to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The usual one-liner:

```
total = sum(map(int, open("mynumbers.txt")))
```

It does generate a list of integers (albeit very temporarily).

Comment: He's on Python 3, so it doesn't even generate a list - this is definitely the most elegant solution (+1), although it's probably a bit much for a beginner, especially without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would go with Tim's answer above, here's another way if you want to use readlines method

```
# Open a file
infile = open('mynumbers.txt', 'r')

sum = 0
lines = infile.readlines()
for num in lines:
    sum += int(num)

print sum
```